# Did Michael Flynn commit treason?

Tags: united-states

### Context

In this [Thread](http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/2221878-Michael-Flynn-committed-Treason) the user titles it '*Michael Flynn committed Treason*'.

He believes that Michael Flynn committed treason, Treason is defined in the [Article III Section 3](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/articleiii) of the U.S. Constitution as:

> Treason against the United States, shall consist only in levying war
>   against them, or in adhering to their enemies, giving them aid and
>   comfort. No person shall be convicted of treason unless on the
>   testimony of two witnesses to the same overt act, or on confession in
>   open court.
>
> The Congress shall have power to declare the punishment of treason,
>   but no attainder of treason shall work corruption of blood, or
>   forfeiture except during the life of the person attainted.

So, I'm not sure how much this would be defined as Treason. From my understanding Treason is defined as someone who the U.S. has declared war on, and they officially haven't done that according to [this article](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/07/18/politics/isis-declaration-of-war/).

> But the U.S. hasn't formally declared war on ISIS -- or on anyone else
>   since 1942, when Congress voted to do so against Nazi Germany allies
>   Bulgaria, Hungary and Romania.

<sup>Am I right in this assertion?</sup>

### Question

Did Michael Flynn commit treason?

Comment: Treason is a crime, not a legitimate political act. That means this is more of a question regarding law than regarding politics. I will migrate it to law.SE.

Comment: So what exactly is the relevant overt act?

Comment: The U.S. has declared war on ISIS per the AUMF of 2001 which has been interpreted to include ISIS because it is a successor organization to one of the organizations described in that joint resolution. Likewise, the U.S. is still at war with North Korea. The U.S. is not at war with Russia, however.

Answer (score 6):

Since the treason statute is quite vague, you have to discover what the details of the law is by looking at precedent. Almost all federal treason convictions in the US have involved declared wars. There is the case of [John Fries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fries%27s_Rebellion#Trials), an early tax rebellion case in 1800, who was pardoned by the president thus rendering the need for legal appeal moot, but this involved armed insurrection and is thus not analogous. All other federal cases have involved people supporting the enemy in case of a declared war. In this specific case, the allegation is that by advocating not working with Syrian Kurds in an assault on Raqqa (because it was thought to be in the best interests of the US in terms of our relationship with Turkey, given the position of the Turkish state w.r.t. Kurds), Flynn benefited ISIS. Compared to various wartime treason convictions, such as [Tokyo Rose and Axis Sally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_convicted_of_treason), the difference between imaginary "aid" in the case of Flynn vs. actual aid in the other cases is so stark that there is no case to be made for a treason charge.

Comment: I don't understand how treason can even be considered in the absence of guilty purpose. Releasing the prisoners in Guantamano would presumably benefit a few genuine enemies as well as many innocents; would it be treason even to suggest this?

Comment: Treason is defined in the United States Constitution and that controlling definition isn't vague at all.

Answer (score 2):

Treason is defined in Article III, Section 3, Clause 1 of the United States Constitution (it is the only constitutionally defined crime):

> Treason against the United States, shall consist only in levying war
>   against them, or in adhering to their enemies, giving them aid and
>   comfort.

The legal meaning of the word "enemy" in the context of treason law, is a country or group upon whom a war has been declared.

Michael Flynn did not levy a war against the United States.

Michael Flynn did not give aid and comfort or adhere to a country with whom the United States was currently in a declared war.

Therefore, Michael Flynn did not commit treason.

Answer (score -3):

It says in times of war, or in adhering to their enemies, giving comfort or aid.

You do not need to be at war to commit treason. Selling top secret information to others is treason.

Lying to our top governing body- sounds like treason to me. 
There is a line of guys waiting to be tried. 
coercion with a foreign government that has known to be involved in comptomising or electoral process.

Flynn should do some jail time.

Comment: You can think he deserves jail time without thinking he committed treason, though.  Lying to the FBI is a crime, but it isn't treason (otherwise Martha Stewart would be guilty of treason.)